# How to fix SVN commit "file is missing" error?

Tags: svn, svncommit

I have a working copy named "Experiments" in that I had to add a project named "Blue Print".

I have done `svn add *`, later I've deleted the "Blue Print" project folder for some reason. Then I've added another project named "MyProj" and used `svn add`.

Now, when I try to commit I'm getting error that "Blue Print" is missing.

I have tried `svn revert "Blue Print"`, `svn delete "Blue Print"`, but have not able to solve the issue. What can I do to fix my working copy and/or repo?

Comment: The biggest and best thing I've ever done to "fix" SVN was to switch to Hg ;-) If you think this is bad, wait until you get into Tree Conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an SVN clean, followed by SVN update.  The Blue Print folder should be placed BACK into your working copy by the SVN update (this is what you want) - it will be an exact copy of what is in the SVN repository.  Then, and only then, with the Blue Print folder present in your working copy exactly as it is in the SVN repository, delete the Blue Print folder from your working copy, and then commit the deletion to the SVN repository.